# AngularJS throwing infdigs from $watch that modifies neither trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have only 1 `$watch` in an AngularJS script as follows:

```
$scope.$watch('[p, q]', function(newVals, oldVals) {
    $scope.n = newVals[0] * newVals[1];
    $scope.phi = (newVals[0] - 1) * (newVals[1] - 1);
});
```

The function modifies neither `p` nor `q`, why is throwing `infdigs` like so?

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%…%20q%5D%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5B5%2C7%5D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%5B5%2C7%5D%22%5D%5D
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js:6:456
    at h.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js:107:164)
    at h.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js:109:287)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js:18:23
    at Object.d [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js:34:211)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js:17:439)
    at cc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js:18:140)
    at ed (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js:17:215)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js:212:459 angular.js:9784
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%…%5B5%2C7%5D%22%5D%2C%5B%22%5Bp%2C%20q%5D%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5B5%2C7%5D%3B%2...<omitted>...5D angular.js:12453
```

EDIT: More relevant code

```
app.controller('RSACtrl', function($scope) {
    // These just set defaults, right?
    $scope.m = 'Hats are cool.';
    $scope.p = 5;
    $scope.q = 7;
    $scope.n = $scope.p * $scope.q;
    $scope.phi = ($scope.p - 1) * ($scope.q - 1);
    $scope.e = 17;
    $scope.d = inverse($scope.e, $scope.n); // Gets modular inverse, purely functional.
    //

    $scope.$watch('[p, q]', function(newVals, oldVals) {
        $scope.n = newVals[0] * newVals[1];
        $scope.phi = (newVals[0] - 1) * (newVals[1] - 1);
    });
}
```

Some HTML

```
    <label>Enter a prime p:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model='p'>
    <br/>
    <label>Enter a prime q:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model='q'>
    <br/>
    <p ng-show='isPrime(p)'> p = {{p}} </p>
    <p ng-show='isPrime(q)'> q = {{q}} </p>
```

No assignment is happening in `{{}}`s

Comment: How are `$scope.n` and `$scope.phi` then used? In a template?

Comment: @MichalCharemza as in a {{}}? Yes. But that shouldn't start a loop, should it?

Comment: I think it depends on how it's used: say if it's then be assigned to other variables, which can be done in `{{}}` interpolated expressions. Can you post it/them?

Comment: are n and phi bound to p and q somehow? Is there something like `$scope.p = $scope.n*$scope.phi;` ? If so, make sure they are not bound by using `angular.copy()`.

Comment: @MichalCharemza Added relevant code/html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in in the watch is an expression evaluated in the context of the scope. Your expression is `[p, q]`, which will create a new array every time. This new reference triggers a new digest cycle, thus the infinite loop. Are you just wanting to run that logic any time `p` or `q` changes? Just watch them separately and call the same function.

```
function doStuff(p, q)
{
    $scope.n = p * q;
    $scope.phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
}

$scope.$watch('p', function(newVal) {
    doStuff(newVal, $scope.q)
}
$scope.$watch('q', function(newVal) {
    doStuff($scope.p, newVal)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you ever watch multiple elements at the same time (e.g. '[p,q]') without this happening?

Comment: Instead of string, you can use a function and just return whatever you want to trigger the listener.